# C# and Jquery Datatables Serverside processing issue

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, datatables, jquery-datatables-editor

I'm returning data from a stored procedure to a jquery Datatable table, but due the amount of returning data, I'm struggling to implement a server side processing and only load data that is requested ( e.i 10,20,50,100 )

Here is my javascript code

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            "dataType": "application/json",
            "type": "GET",
            "url": "http://localhost:54888/api/order",
            "success": function (dataStr) {
                console.log(dataStr.responseText);
                // laod Data to DataTable Jquery
                var resp =  jQuery.parseJSON(dataStr.responseText ? dataStr.responseText : dataStr);
                $('#example').DataTable({
                    data: resp["rows"],
                    columns: resp["aoColumns"],
                    scrollX: true,
                    autoWidth: true,
                    bScrollCollapse: true,
                   // paging: true,
                   // retrieve: true,
                    "jQueryUI": true,
                   // serverSide: true,
                    processing:true

                });
            },
            "error": function (dataStr) {
                //console.log(dataStr);
                var resp = jQuery.parseJSON(dataStr.responseText ? dataStr.responseText : dataStr);
                $('#example').DataTable({

                    data: resp["rows"],
                    columns: resp["aoColumns"],
                    scrollX: true,
                    autoWidth: true,
                    bScrollCollapse: true,
                    //paging: true,
                    //retrieve: true,
                    "jQueryUI": true,
                   // serverSide: true,
                    processing: true
                });

            }
        })
    });
```

i there a great way to filter the data to only what the user is looking at? instead of loading all 500K records.

Many Thanks

Comment: this might help: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1170086/Grid-with-Server-Side-Advanced-Search-using-JQuery

Comment: thanks for your response, unfortunately  I have looked at tthat article and i  didn't help much

Comment: Can you make the data coming from the stored procedure asynchronous? That would help. But c# has a way sending a number of data to a view

Comment: Hello @lutakyn I just tried making my sp asynchronous.. without success

Comment: I would recommend setting up the DataTable with a serverside implementation and let it control the ajax call.  The DataTable api will send parameters for the starting record and record count so that the back end can limit the rows returned in the query.  Right now, the datatable is essentially client side because all the data is loading into the entire table.  https://datatables.net/manual/server-side

Comment: hi @PaulZepernick that doesnt work either

Comment: @Yosh I would recommend updating your question with what you have tried exactly